# stdClass Object containing array() of objects. How do I count elements in nested object

Tags: php

The following statements:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Yield the result:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [tickets] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
            ['SomeData']
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
            ['SomeData']
            )
        [2]
            ...
    )
)
```

I'd like to count the total entires inside[tickets].

I have tried:

`print_r(array_count_values())`

and:

```
$totalResults = 0;
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $totalResults++;
}
//echo $totalResults;
```

The former yields `Warning: array_count_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in...`

*** edit ***

The following:

```
$total = count((array)$result);
echo $total;
```

Yields the value 4 when I know the output should be well over 100.

Comment: I will try that immediately and report so this question can be deleted.

Comment: Why not `count($result->tickets);`?